# Python - Sort a list by a certain element in a tuple in a dictionary

Tags: python

`data = [{'info': ('orange', 400000, 'apple'), 'photo': None}, {'info': ('grape', 485000, 'watermelon'), 'photo': None}]`

I want to sort `data` by the 2nd element (400000, 485000) in the tuple in the dictionary.  How do I do this?

I followed another answer and my closest attempt was `data.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])`, but that produces this error:

> KeyError: 1

Comment: `data.sort(key=lambda x: x['info'][1])`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes that's what I need.  You should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the inplace `list.sort` method with a `key` that indexes `info` *first*, and *then* the data in the tuple:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: x['info'][1])
```

Or, the *not* in-place `sorted` function:

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['info'][1])
```

Between the two, `list.sort` is faster, because it sorts the data in-place, whereas `sorted` has to create and return a copy of the data in `data`.

A couple of other things you should think about;

1. What if your dictionary does not have `info` as a key?
2. What if the second element in the `info` tuple isn't even numeric?

Do you want `sort` to error out when it hits invalid data? Or would you rather introduce some means of handling these on a case-by-case basis? The `key` would need to change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort via `key`:

```
data = [{'info': ('orange', 400000, 'apple'), 'photo': None}, {'info': ('grape', 485000, 'watermelon'), 'photo': None}]
new_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x:x.get('info', [0, 0])[1])
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `['info']` instead of `.get` here. I'd rather the code would error out on a missing key instead of introducing arbitrary workarounds for it.

Answer (score 0):

For each dict item in the list you want to sort, you want to take the item's value keyed by 'info', which is a list, and sort on the second item (addressed as [1], counting from zero.

So: `data.sort(key=lambda item: item['info'][1])`